# Get values till until a character(include the checking character) using stringbuilder

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, boundary

How to check if a begining of line is `"A"` followed with anything is `Ablahblablah`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String[] lines1 = sb.toString().split("\\n");
for(String getVal: lines1){
 while(getVal.contains("^A\\w*")){
    temp.append(getVal);//If found store all the former values and line including A + 2 characters in a temp buffer
  }
}
System.out.println("temp = " + temp.toString());
```

output

```
temp =
```

Temp returns empty.

Am I doing anything wrong.

**UPDATE**

used : `if(getVal.startsWith("6000")){`

I am getting the desired output.
Any issues in this logic.

how to delete the `temp` from existing **sb**?

Comment: To match string against regex - you have to use method `String.matches(...)` (see javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String))

Comment: Why don't you use charAt(0) and check the value is 'A' or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks every one

I found the answer

```
String[] lines1 = sb.toString().split("\\n");
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
for(String getVal: lines1){
 if(getVal.startsWith("6000")){
     temp.append(getVal);
     break;
 }
 else{
     temp.append(getVal);
 }
 temp.append("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `matches()` method, not `contains()`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do

```
if (getVal.startWith("A")) {
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
.
.
.
String[] lines1 = sb.toString().split("\\n");
for(String getVal: lines1){
 while(getVal.matches("A\\w*")){
    temp.append(getVal);//If found store all the former values and line including A + 2 characters in a temp buffer
  }
}
System.out.println("temp = " + temp.toString());
```

Comment: used if(getVal.startsWith("6000")){

Answer (score -1):

Its because of scope of temp.have you declared variable temp outside of loop?